# Kafka Stream Chained LeftJoin - Processing previous old message again after the new one

Tags: java, apache-kafka, left-join, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream that is a composite of other streams

```java
final KTable<Long, CompositeInfo> compositeInfoTable = compositeImcTable
    .leftJoin(
        compositeFundTable, 
        (CompositeImc cimc, CompositeFund cf) -> {
            CompositeInfo newCandidate = new CompositeInfo();
            if (cimc != null) {
                newCandidate.imcName = cimc.imcName;
                newCandidate.imcID = cimc.imcID;                                                                    
                if (cf != null) {
                    newCandidate.investments = cf.investments;
                }
            }
            return newCandidate;
        })
    .leftJoin(
        compositeGeographyTable, 
        (CompositeInfo cinfo, CompositeGeography cg) -> {
            if (cg != null) {
                cinfo.regions = cg.regions;
            }
            return cinfo;
        })
    .leftJoin(
        compositeSectorTable, 
        (CompositeInfo cinfo, CompositeSector cs) -> {
            if (cs != null) {
                cinfo.sectors = cs.sectors;
            }
            return cinfo;
        })
    .leftJoin(
        compositeClusterTable, 
        (CompositeInfo cinfo, CustomCluster cc) -> {
            if (cc != null && cc.clusters != null) {
                cinfo.clusters = cc.clusters;
            }
            return cinfo;
        })
    .leftJoin(
        compositeAlphaClusterTable, 
        (CompositeInfo cinfo, CompositeAlphaCluster cac) -> {
            if (cac != null) {
                cinfo.alphaClusters = cac.alphaClusters;
            };
            return cinfo;
        },
        Materialized.<Long, CompositeInfo, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(this.storeName)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
            .withValueSerde(compositeInfoSerde));
```

My issue relates to the left join between CompositeInfo and CustomCluster. CustomCluster looks like the following

```java
KTable<Long, CustomCluster> compositeClusterTable = builder
    .stream(
        SUB_TOPIC_COMPOSITE_CLUSTER,
        Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), compositeClusterSerde))
    .filter((k, v) -> v.clusters != null)
    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), compositeClusterSerde))
    .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> newValue);
```

A message in a custom cluster looks like

```
CustomCluster [clusterId=null, clusterName=null, compositeId=280, operation=null, clusters=[Cluster [clusterId=6041, clusterName=MyName]]]
```

So I assign the HashMap clusters in this object to the clusters in CompositeInfo object joined on the compositeId.

What I am witnessing is that a CustomCluster message comes in for a given compositeId an dis processed correctly but then the old message containing the previous cluster (I am still investigating this) is processed again. 
Upon digging through the problem happens in kafka internal KTableKTableRightJoin

```java
public void process(final K key, final Change<V1> change) {
    // we do join iff keys are equal, thus, if key is null we cannot join and just ignore the record
    if (key == null) {
        return;
    }

    final R newValue;
    R oldValue = null;

    final V2 value2 = valueGetter.get(key);
    if (value2 == null) {
        return;
    }

    newValue = joiner.apply(change.newValue, value2);

    if (sendOldValues) {
        oldValue = joiner.apply(change.oldValue, value2);
    }

    context().forward(key, new Change<>(newValue, oldValue));
}
```

when the joine returns the first time, the newValue is updated correctly. But the code then goes to sendOldValues block and as soon as the joiner returns, the newValue is update gain but this time with old cluster value.

So here are my questions:

1. Why is newValues getting updated when the joiner is called the
   second time with oldValue
2. Is there a way to turn sendOldValues off
3. Does my chained left-joins would have anything to do with it. I know
   previous versions of kafka had a bug with chaining. But now I am on
   1.0

**UPDATE:**
Another thing I found. If I move join up the chain of joins and remove others, the sendOldValues remains False. So if I have something like the following:

```java
final KTable<Long, CompositeInfo> compositeInfoTable = compositeImcTable
    .leftJoin(
        compositeFundTable, 
        (CompositeImc cimc, CompositeFund cf) -> {
            CompositeInfo newCandidate = new CompositeInfo();
            if (cimc != null) {
                newCandidate.imcName = cimc.imcName;
                newCandidate.imcID = cimc.imcID;
                if (cf != null) {
                    newCandidate.investments = cf.investments;
                }
            }   
            return newCandidate;
        })
    .leftJoin(
        compositeClusterTable, 
        (CompositeInfo cinfo, CustomCluster cc) -> {
            if (cc != null && cc.clusters != null) {
                cinfo.clusters = cc.clusters;
            }
            return cinfo;
        },
        Materialized.<Long, CompositeInfo, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(this.storeName)
          .withKeySerde(Serdes.Long())
          .withValueSerde(compositeInfoSerde));
```

This gives me the correct result. But I think that if I put any more chained joins after this they might display the same erroneous behavior.

I am not certain of anything at this point but I think my problem lies in **chained leftjoin** and the behavior of calculating **oldValue**. Has anyone else run into this issue?

**UPDATE**

After much digging through I realize that sendOldValues is internal to kafka and not the cause of issue I am experiencing. My issue is that the newValue changes when the ValueJoiner for oldValue returns and I dont know if its due to some pass by reference assignment to Java objects

This is what an incoming object looks like

```
CustomCluster [clusterId=null, clusterName=null, compositeId=280, operation=null, clusters=[Cluster [clusterId=6041, clusterName=Sunil 2]]]
```

clusters is a `HashSet<Cluster> clusters = new HashSet<Cluster>();`

It is then joined to an object

```
CompositeInfo [compositeName=BUCKET_NM-280, compositeID=280, imcID=19651, regions=null, sectors=null, clusters=[]]
```

the clusters here is of the same type but in CompositeInfo class

When I join, I assign clusters of CustomCluster object to CompositeInfo object

```java
(CompositeInfo cinfo, CustomCluster cc) -> {
    if (cc != null && cc.clusters != null) {
        cinfo.clusters = cc.clusters;
    }
    return cinfo;
}
```

Comment: What do yo mean by "But the code then goes to sendOldValues block and as soon as the joiner returns, the newValue is update gain but this time with old cluster value." The `if (sendOldValue)` statements sets `oldValue = ` but not `newValue =`.

Comment: "Is there a way to turn sendOldValues off". Not really and it would most likely lead to incorrect results -- `sendOldValues` is used to a guarantee correct computation.

Comment: `KTable#leftJoin()` requires `sendOldValues` to compute the correct result.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Please see the last update. I realize that my issue isn't sendOldValues. I have an object that contains a HashMap. This comprises new and old values. When the joiner for oldValue code block returns it somehow changes the HashMap inside newValue

Comment: I solved it. It was indeed a pass by reference issue. When joining, I need to initialize and return a new object rather than assign value to the old object

Comment: Makes sense. Glad you figure it out :)

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks. I am still a little skeptical about my code though. This means that on every left join I'll have to instantiate a new object and copy all the attributed from the chain above. Doesn't look very efficient

Comment: Do you actually see a performance issue? One should avoid premature optimization :)

Comment: We don't really produce that many messages to see a performance lag. I do see multiple messages being emmitted for a single change and I am trying to understand why. But still, you would think that if you are joining n tables, instantiating n new objects instead of just one will have an overhead.So just trying to see if I am going about it the wrong way

Comment: "I do see multiple messages being emmitted for a single change and I am trying to understand why.": check out the docs -> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Join+Semantics -- this should help to understand the semantics

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After stumbling on the same issue myself, I would like to provide a detailed answer as well as a simplified example that helps illustrating the problem.

```
  @Bean
  public Function<KTable<String, String>,
    Function<KTable<String, String>, Consumer<KTable<String, String>>>> processEvents() {
    return firstnames ->
      lastnames ->
        titles -> firstnames
          .mapValues(firstname -> new Salutation().withFirstname(firstname))
          .join(lastnames, (salutation, lastname) -> salutation.withLastname(lastname))
          .leftJoin(titles, (salutation, title) -> salutation.withTitle(title))
          .toStream()
          .foreach((key, salutation) -> log.info("{}: {}", key, salutation));
  }
```

The example (which uses Spring Cloud Stream with the Kafka Streams binder) shows a common pattern where topics contents are merged into an accumulator object. In our case, a salutation (e.g. "Dear Ms. Smith") is accumulated/aggregated into a `Salutation` object by joining topics representing the firstname, lastname and an (optional) title.

It is important to note that in this example, the `Salutation` instance is a mutable object that is constructed step by step. When running such a piece of code, you will see that when changing a person's last name, the merge will always be "running behind". This means that if you publish a lastname event because Ms. Smith has just got married and is now called "Johnson", then Kafka Streams will again emit a `Salutation` representing "Ms. Smith", despite the fact that she changed her last name. It is only when you publish yet another event for the same person on the lastnames topic (e.g. "Miller") that "Dear Ms. Johnson" will be logged.

The reason for this behavior is found in a piece of code located in `KTableKTableInnerJoin.java`:

```
if (change.newValue != null) {
    newValue = joiner.apply(change.newValue, valueRight);
}

if (sendOldValues && change.oldValue != null) {
    oldValue = joiner.apply(change.oldValue, valueRight);
}

context().forward(key, new Change<>(newValue, oldValue), To.all().withTimestamp(resultTimestamp));
```

`joiner` is a `ValueJoiner`, which in our case can e.g. be `(salutation, lastname) -> salutation.withLastname(lastname)` as shown above. The problem with this piece of code is that if you use an accumulation pattern with a mutable accumulator object (in our case an instance of `Salutation`), which is (by design) reused for all the joins, then `oldValue` and `newValue` will be the same object. Moreover, since `oldValue` is computed afterwards, it will contain the old last name, which explains why Spring Kafka is running behind.

Therefore, it is critical that the object returned by the `ValueJoiner` is each time a fresh object which does not contain references to other mutable objects, which might be shared (and therefore mutated). The safest approach is therefore to have the `ValueJoiner` return an immutable object.

I would not consider this as a bug of the library, since it has to compare the old and new state somehow, and since taking a snaphsot of a mutable object would require a deep copy. However, it would probably be worthwhile to have it mentioned in the documentation. Also, issuing a warning when `oldValue == newValue` would at least make people aware of the problem. I will check whether such improvements could be incorporated.

Comment: An excellent answer than lead to a solution to my problem!

Another way to state this pitfall: do not return either parameter of a join -- always create something new.

BAD:  `(x, y) -> { x.setThing(...); return x }`

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed a pass by reference issue. When joining, I need to initialize and return a new object rather than assign value to the old object.

<sub>Answer based upon [fizi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51565727/kafka-stream-chained-leftjoin-processing-previous-old-message-again-after-the/68952201#comment90203836_51565727) comments on question.</sub>